# How can I get pyautoGUI's typewrite function to type only on a specific tab?

Tags: python, pyautogui

I am trying to type a message on a specific tab in google, but pyautoGUI's typewrite function types on whatever tab is opened rather than the specific tab I want it to type on. How can I get it to type only on a specific window regardless of whichever other window or tab is open?

Comment: I believe you want to share what you had tried so far or what you had found while researching about your problem.

Comment: I want to type something on an opened tab on google e.g(any website) but when i use pyautogui's typewrite function it works BUT only when the tab is open otherwise it just types on whatever window i am using, i want it to search some text on the specific website regardless of what window is opened

Answer (score -1):

Maybe you can use the webbrowser module. It's a convenient web-browser controller. More documentation is found here: https://docs.python.org/3/library/webbrowser.html